# Using dictionary in flask

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

i trying to use a dict in my flask app to generate a pair Name - One Time Password for new users.
(Yes, i know what using a database is prefered and better, but now i need only dict)

```
account = session['user_id']
token = secrets.token_hex(16)
users = ({account: {'Login': account, 'Secret': token}})
Name = users[account]['Login']
Key = users[account]['Secret']
print(users[account])
```

Pairs name key will be pushed to next webpage.

If i understand correctly, every time user reloading page or another user attempts to get a key a dict will be re-created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will create a new one each time and you can prevent it by checking the value of the dictionary.